# Change React Native header bar background colour in nested stack navigator

Tags: reactjs, tabs, navigation, stack, native

I have a tab navigator with a stack navigator nested inside it. No matter what I try, I can only get the tab bar to change colour, but not the header bar. It won't change at all. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, what I did was to design the header on every tab (3 screens) and it looked totally the same.

So you can create the Header component and load it where you need, if anyone has a better solution it will be very helpful because I searched every where and couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: Can you walk me through what I need to do to achieve this? I feel like I've tried everything!

Comment: You wanna add header to every tab right? my problem was that when the app loads, a sign in form shows up and there is a header, after user signs in and see the tabs, header disappeared, so I built a custom Header component that mimics the styles of the header of the Stack Navigator

Comment: when I switched between tabs the Header text did not update, it updated when Stack.Navigator route changed but not Tab.Navigator.. so what I did, removed header when user signs in and when tabs load, a customized header is shown on every tab.

Comment: That really sucks if that's the only way to do it...I need to use the nested stack navigator so that would be super annoying! Thanks for the suggestion. I am gonna keep trying but may resort to that if necessary.

Comment: yep, unfortunately I couldn't find any solution so I came up with this idea :) if that helped you please mark & vote my answer :)